# How to test lambda using test event

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have lambda which is triggered by cloudwatch event when VPN tunnels are down or up. I searched online but can't find a way to trigger this cloudwatch event. 
I see an option for test event but what can I enter in here for it to trigger an event that tunnel is up or down?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [CloudWatchEventsandEventPatterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatchEventsandEventPatterns.html)

> Events in Amazon CloudWatch Events are represented as JSON objects.
>   For more information about JSON objects, see [RFC 7159](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt). The following
>   is an example event:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "6a7e8feb-b491-4cf7-a9f1-bf3703467718",
  "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
  "source": "aws.ec2",
  "account": "111122223333",
  "time": "2017-12-22T18:43:48Z",
  "region": "us-west-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789012:instance/ i-1234567890abcdef0"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "instance-id": " i-1234567890abcdef0",
    "state": "terminated"
  }
}
```

Also log based on event, you can pick your required event from [AWS CW EventTypes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/EventTypes.html)

Comment: VPN Tunnels are not in CW EventTypes list.

Comment: Oh so you are looking for some custom event, write a script that check health of VPN tunnel, if it fail then write event to CW and based on that event trigger your lambda, or you can configure some LB check to check if the target is unhealthy then trigger the lambda.

Comment: No i have created cw alarm which triggers labmda when tunnels are down. Now I am trying to test by invoking cw alarm and I dont know how to invoke the cw alarm.

Comment: can you grab one event from the CW? and pass it to lambda?

Comment: I can that wont be right test as it will not indicate that tunnel is in down sate.

Comment: `aws cloudwatch set-alarm-state --alarm-name "myalarm" --state-value ALARM --state-reason "tunnel is down"` ?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/set-alarm-state.html

Comment: I think it would be more easy to sense the health check as target of LB? https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/identifying-unhealthy-targets-of-elastic-load-balancer/

Answer (score 0):

I believe in your scenario, you don't need to pass any input data as you must have built the logic to test the VPN tunnels connectivity within the Lamda. You can remove that JSON from the test event and then run the test.

If you need to pass in some information as part of the input event then follow the approach mentioned by @Adiii.

**EDIT** 
The question is more clear through the comment which says

> But question is how will I trigger the lambda? Lets say I want to
>   trigger it when tunnel is down? How will let lambda know tunnel is in
>   down state? – NoviceMe

This can be achieved by setting up a rule in Cloudwatch to schedule the lambda trigger at a periodic interval. More details here:

[Tutorial: Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)

Lambda does not have an invocation trigger right now that can monitor a VPN tunnel, so the only workaround is to poll the status through lamda.

Comment: But question is how will I trigger the lambda? Lets say I want to trigger it when tunnel is down? How will let lambda know tunnel is in down state?

Comment: @NoviceMe It wasn't clear in your original question. Updated my answer to provide you the details to use AWS Cloudwatch to setup schedule to invoke your lambda periodically.